# Django-REST: The database driver doesn't support modern datatime types

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, odbc, freetds

I'm trying to make a rest API with Django Rest on Debian, 
but when I run the command "python3 manage.py migrate" throws this exception

**Error**: The database driver doesn't support modern datatime types.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The database driver doesn't support modern datatime types.

**Already installed:**

```
msodbcsql17 is already the newest version (17.3.1.1-1).
freetds-bin is already the newest version (0.91-6.1+b4).
freetds-dev is already the newest version (0.91-6.1+b4).
tdsodbc is already the newest version (0.91-6.1+b4).
unixodbc-dev is already the newest version (2.3.7).
unixodbc is already the newest version (2.3.7).
```

**file**:odbc.ini

```
[MYSERVER]
Description         = Django SQLServer
Driver              = FreeTDS
Trace               = Yes
TraceFile           = /tmp/sql.log
Database            = DjangoDB
Servername          = MYSERVER
UserName            = sa
Password            = *******
Port                = 1433
Protocol            = 8.0
```

**file**:odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL on Win32
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup =/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

**file**:freetds.conf

```
[global]
# TDS protocol version
tds version = 8.0

[MYSERVER]
host = localhost
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your TDS Version. Version 8.0 isn't actually a valid version, despite a lot of bad advice existing across the Internet. There are a lot of reasons for this, but Version 8.0 actually maps to TDS Version 7.1, which was before Microsoft adding new date and time field types in SQL Server 2008. See the footnote here:

https://www.freetds.org/userguide/tdshistory.htm

You're running a pretty old version of FreeTDS (0.91). It only supports TDS Version 7.2, which was introduced in SQL Server 2005. I would recommend upgrading your version of FreeTDS, and using TDS Version 7.3. Details here:

https://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

The other option is to use the MS ODBC driver you seem to have installed already, which is much more up-to-date than the version of FreeTDS you have.

Good luck!

Comment: Updating:

freetds-bin is already the newest version (0.91-6.1+b4).
freetds-dev is already the newest version (0.91-6.1+b4).
tdsodbc is already the newest version (0.91-6.1+b4).
to newer version and setting FreeTDS to versin 7,4 fixed the problem.